# Как прижать footer к низу?

Tags: css

Как прижать footer к низу?
http://banya.sctraduga.ru/ceny

Comment: http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/karkas-verstki/podval-k-nizu.html

Comment: А зачем вам 2 футера?

    #podval { 
        height: 64px;
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Убрать `<div id='podval'>`, который сразу после футера. Все равно он пустой. Или высоту ему поставить `0px`, или сделать `display='none'`, в конце концов.

Comment: убрав ее ниче не изменится,мне просто нужен после footer участок с таким цветом